# Could a contract permits ERC20 token to an EOA account?

Tags: solidity, eoa

We know that EOA account has private key, so EOA account could permits other EOA accounts to use his token. But can contract permits an EOA account? The following is my question:

1. Could contract permits EOA account if contract has ERC20 token?
2. Could contract permits contract if contract has ERC20 token?
3. Could EOA account permits contract if EOA account has ERC20 token?

This is my code logic: Contract A has 10 ERC20 token in contract B, if contract A has permit(), could A permits an EOA account to use his ERC20 token?

Comment: @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol

Comment: is Contract B an ERC20 contract, and is Contract A a special contract? What do you mean with "contract A has permit()" do you mean it has a function called permit?

Comment: contract A inherits ERC20permit so it has permit(). Contract B inherits ERC20, we call B.balanceOf(contract A) = 10EHT. Then ,can we A.permit(EOA) that EOA proxy its 10ETH?[EOA proxy contract A 's 10 ETH]

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the contract can call ERC(token).approve(eEOA, cmount)
2. exactly the same, yes.
3. Yes, indeed, this is the classical interaction with a defi protocol, when you approve the defi contract to transfer your tokens.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is there an example that i can reference?

Answer (score 0):

> But can contract permits an EOA account?

I assume what you're talking about here is the permit() function from ERC20Permit, and not the approve function from the normal ERC20 standard. In that case, *theorically*, it's possible, you'd have to find "the contracts private keys" (a private key that resolves to the contracts address, i mean, you couldnt *actually* sign transactions with it, at least not on the network(s) where a contract is deployed at that address) and construct a permit from that private key.

Comment: Yes I said the permit() function from ERC20Permit. I know it is not possible to find a contract private key and its private key is not work in the ethereum.Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, smart contract signatures are regulated by [EIP-1271](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271) (usage example can be found here: [openzeppelin/ERC1271WalletMock.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.8.0/contracts/mocks/ERC1271WalletMock.sol)).

But permit standard ([EIP-2612](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612)) defines signature components as following:

> `r`, `s` and `v` is a valid `secp256k1` signature from `owner`

Most popular [implementation by OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/49c0e4370d0cc50ea6090709e3835a3091e33ee2/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol#L64) checks signature the following way:

```
ECDSA.recover(hash, v, r, s);
```

If they used [SignatureChecker](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.8.0/contracts/utils/cryptography/SignatureChecker.sol) to check the signature, this would be possible.

But smart contract wallet could implement `permit`-like functionality based on it's owner signature:

```
contract Vault is Ownable, EIP712 {
    bytes32 public constant TOKEN_PERMIT_TYPEHASH = keccak256(
        "TokenPermit("
            "address token,"
            "address spender,"
            "uint256 value,"
            "uint256 nonce,"
            "uint256 deadline"
        ")"
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public nonces;

    function tokenPermit(
        address token,
        address spender,
        uint256 value,
        uint256 deadline,
        bytes memory signature,
    ) external {
        require(block.timestamp <= deadline, "ERC20Permit: expired deadline");

        bytes32 structHash = keccak256(abi.encode(TOKEN_PERMIT_TYPEHASH, token, spender, value, nonces[spender]++, deadline));

        bytes32 hash = _hashTypedDataV4(structHash);

        address signer = SignatureChecker.isValidSignatureNow(owner(), hash, signature);
        require(signer == owner(), "TokenPermit: invalid signature");

        IERC20(token).approve(spender, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if I want that a contract "permit" its token to other EOA or contract, I must implement eip-1271. Permit() from ERC20Permit can not do that because it only allows EOA to permits  EOA. right?

Comment: @user19646633 correct!